# Swift: How to add new property to UIImageView class?

Tags: swift, class, properties

I'm afraid I'm relatively new to Swift, but have looked around as best I could and haven't been able to figure out how to do this relatively simple task!

I would like to add a new property called "angle" to the class UIImageView, such that you could use "image.angle".  Here's what I've got, having attempted to follow the method of a tutorial I used (note that the required init? part was suggested by Xcode and I am not too sure of what it does):

```
class selection_image: UIImageView {

    var angle = Double()

    init(angle: Double) {
        self.angle = angle
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Thank you very much for any help!!

Comment: What do you want `angle` to describe? The rotation of the image?

Comment: Class names begin with an uppercase letter, use camel case and should be descriptive of what they are. `selection_image` should really be `SelectionImageView`.

Comment: What's wrong with your code then? It seems fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
class selection_image: UIImageView {

    var angle = Double()

    // your new Init
  required convenience  init(angle: Double) {
        self.init(frame: CGRect.zero)

        self.angle = angle
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Comment: You can used extention

Comment: No you cannot use extension for that. Extensions cannot contain stored properties.

Comment: We can add a property in an Extension using AssociatedObjects.   See my answer below:

Answer (score 1):

**Using Swift 4.2**

@jasperthedog. You can add a property to a given class using AssociatedObjects of the Runtime using an extension as follows:

In this example, I add an optional viewAlreadyAppeared: Bool? property to UIViewController. And with this, I avoid creating subclasses of UIViewController

```
extension UIViewController {
    private struct CustomProperties {
        static var viewAlreadyAppeared: Bool? = nil
    }
    var viewAlreadyAppeared: Bool? {
        get {
            return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &CustomProperties.viewAlreadyAppeared) as? Bool
        }
        set {
            if let unwrappedValue  = newValue {
                objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &CustomProperties.viewAlreadyAppeared, unwrappedValue as Bool?, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)
            }
        }
    }
}
```